# Redash customization

Tags: amazon-web-services, customization, dashboard, redash

I have redash set up on aws using the ami, I was wondering if I can change the redash logo on the ui? Also can I change the redash name to any of my choice? If so, what are the steps? As I can’t seem to find it anywhere online.

I tried editing the /opt/redash/docker-compose.yaml file & added this under services
version: "2"
x-redash-service: &redash-service
image: redash/redash:8.0.0.b32245
depends_on:
- postgres
- redis
env_file: /opt/redash/env
restart: always
services:
server:
<<: *redash-service
command: server
ports:
- "5000:5000"
environment:
REDASH_WEB_WORKERS: 4
volumes:
- /path/to/my/custom-logo.png:/app/client/app/assets/images/redash_icon_small.png